# Modern HTML5 Audio Library

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm searching for a modern JS Audio Library. Some like SM2.

1. 100% Web Audio API based
2. Without flash fallback.
3. Easy to use and expand

It will be cool if:

1. It can change pitch of audio file
2. It can create waveform (like http://wavesurfer-js.org/)